# Is this n-ary weighted tree implementation idiomatic rust? I find it too repetitive

Tags: rust, tree, traversal, idioms, code-duplication

## Context and description of the encountered problem

Currently I'm learning the Rust Programming Language and last weekend I found myself implementing a generic *n*-Ary weighted tree data structure whose Nodes are of type `N` and edges of type `E`.

I was browsing the std docs and found the `Iterator` trait and was tempted to implement it for this datastructure. But there is a caveat: There are **several** reasonable ways to traverse a tree datastructure that I wanted to implement:

- preorder
- postorder
- inorder

Additionally, I want one iterator to yield &references and one to yield exclusive references &mut for all of the previously named traversal options thus having to **implement 6 Iterators** where 3 just differ in mutability from the other 3 for my data structure. Furthermore I want to **stay away from macros** if possible (although I can imagine them to be helpful here)!

Naturally this leads to some (minimal? for my taste a bit too much) code duplication.

## Current Implementation

The generic node data structure has two relevant methods:

`pub fn traverse_ref(&self, traverse: Traverse) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &Self> + '_>`

`pub fn traverse_mut(&mut self, traverse: Traverse) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &mut Self> + '_>`

where `Traverse` is an enum holding all supported ways of traversing the tree.

They return boxes of the proper iterator-structs `Traversal<'t, N, E, M>` and `TraversalMut<'t, N, E, M>`, respectively,
where `N` and `E` are the generics of the tree and `M` is a type which specifies which kind of traversal takes place.

My attempt at reducing duplication lies in the fact that I added a `Traveller` trait whose methods handle the various kinds of iteration thus having to only call the proper method of that trait in both of my `Iterator` implementations for a given traversal method.

**This seems repetetive.**

### API example (main.rs)

```
mod tree;

fn main() {
    use std::num::NonZeroU8;
    use tree::Node;

    let mut tree = Node::new(NonZeroU8::new(1));

    tree.add_children(NonZeroU8::new(2), true);
    tree.add_children(NonZeroU8::new(3), false);

    tree.get_children_mut()[0]
        .0
        .add_children(NonZeroU8::new(4), true);
    tree.get_children_mut()[0]
        .0
        .add_children(NonZeroU8::new(5), false);

    for node in tree.traverse_ref(tree::Traverse::PreOrder) {}
}
```

### tree.rs

> Note that the actual implementations of the traversal algorithms were elided to increase readability as they don't matter for the faced problem. Instead I provided a simple `todo!()`.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

mod internal {
    pub trait Sealed {}
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<N, E> {
    value: N,
    children: Vec<(Node<N, E>, E)>,
}

impl<N, E> Node<N, E> {
    pub fn new(value: N) -> Self {
        Self {
            value,
            children: vec![],
        }
    }

    pub fn add_children(&mut self, value: N, edge: E) {
        self.children.push((Node::new(value), edge));
    }

    pub fn get_children_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<(Self, E)> {
        &mut self.children
    }

    pub fn get_value_mut(&mut self) -> &mut N {
        &mut self.value
    }

    pub fn set_value(&mut self, new_value: N) {
        self.value = new_value;
    }

    pub fn traverse_ref(&self, traverse: Traverse) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &Self> + '_> {
        match traverse {
            Traverse::InOrder => Box::new(Traversal::<N, E, InOrder>::new(self)),
            Traverse::PostOrder => Box::new(Traversal::<N, E, PostOrder>::new(self)),
            Traverse::PreOrder => Box::new(Traversal::<N, E, PreOrder>::new(self)),
        }
    }

    pub fn traverse_mut(&mut self, traverse: Traverse) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &mut Self> + '_> {
        match traverse {
            Traverse::InOrder => Box::new(TraversalMut::<N, E, InOrder>::new(self)),
            Traverse::PostOrder => Box::new(TraversalMut::<N, E, PostOrder>::new(self)),
            Traverse::PreOrder => Box::new(TraversalMut::<N, E, PreOrder>::new(self)),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Traverse {
    PreOrder,
    PostOrder,
    InOrder,
}

pub trait TraverseMethod: internal::Sealed {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct PreOrder {}
impl internal::Sealed for PreOrder {}
impl TraverseMethod for PreOrder {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct InOrder {}
impl internal::Sealed for InOrder {}
impl TraverseMethod for InOrder {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct PostOrder {}
impl internal::Sealed for PostOrder {}
impl TraverseMethod for PostOrder {}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Traversal<'t, N, E, M>
where
    M: TraverseMethod,
{
    tree: &'t Node<N, E>,
    _marker: PhantomData<M>,
}

impl<'t, N, E, M> Traversal<'t, N, E, M>
where
    M: TraverseMethod,
{
    fn new(tree: &'t Node<N, E>) -> Self {
        Self {
            tree,
            _marker: PhantomData {},
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TraversalMut<'t, N, E, M>
where
    M: TraverseMethod,
{
    tree: &'t mut Node<N, E>,
    _marker: PhantomData<M>,
}

impl<'t, N, E, M> TraversalMut<'t, N, E, M>
where
    M: TraverseMethod,
{
    fn new(tree: &'t mut Node<N, E>) -> Self {
        Self {
            tree,
            _marker: PhantomData {},
        }
    }
}

trait Traveller {
    type Item;

    fn travel_preorder(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        todo!()
    }

    fn travel_postorder(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        todo!()
    }

    fn travel_inorder(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl<'t, N, E> Traveller for Traversal<'t, N, E, PreOrder> {
    type Item = &'t Node<N, E>;
}

impl<'t, N, E> Iterator for Traversal<'t, N, E, PreOrder> {
    type Item = &'t Node<N, E>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.travel_preorder()
    }
}

impl<'t, N, E> Traveller for TraversalMut<'t, N, E, PreOrder> {
    type Item = &'t mut Node<N, E>;
}

impl<'t, N, E> Iterator for TraversalMut<'t, N, E, PreOrder> {
    type Item = &'t mut Node<N, E>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.travel_preorder()
    }
}

impl<'t, N, E> Traveller for Traversal<'t, N, E, PostOrder> {
    type Item = &'t Node<N, E>;
}

impl<'t, N, E> Iterator for Traversal<'t, N, E, PostOrder> {
    type Item = &'t Node<N, E>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.travel_postorder()
    }
}

impl<'t, N, E> Traveller for TraversalMut<'t, N, E, PostOrder> {
    type Item = &'t mut Node<N, E>;
}

impl<'t, N, E> Iterator for TraversalMut<'t, N, E, PostOrder> {
    type Item = &'t mut Node<N, E>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.travel_postorder()
    }
}

impl<'t, N, E> Traveller for Traversal<'t, N, E, InOrder> {
    type Item = &'t Node<N, E>;
}

impl<'t, N, E> Iterator for Traversal<'t, N, E, InOrder> {
    type Item = &'t Node<N, E>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.travel_inorder()
    }
}

impl<'t, N, E> Traveller for TraversalMut<'t, N, E, InOrder> {
    type Item = &'t mut Node<N, E>;
}

impl<'t, N, E> Iterator for TraversalMut<'t, N, E, InOrder> {
    type Item = &'t mut Node<N, E>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.travel_inorder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you say that the actual traversal implementations don't matter, I assume you're talking about "duplication" in terms of boilerplate code that all looks similar not in terms of actual logic? There's no real way to be generic over ownership semantics in Rust (i.e. `&T` vs `&mut T` vs `T`). I know you'd like to avoid them, but declarative macros are meant for exactly this kind of boilderplate reduction.

Comment: Nitpick: my recommendation is to not use an `enum` for the traversal type, and instead provide separate method for each iterator type. Yes, this will mean you cannot choose the traversal type at runtime without extra boilerplate, but this is not so common request and you get to avoid the performance penalty of boxing and `dyn Trait` by returning `impl Iterator` (or directly `Traversal`).

Comment: Stack Overflow is generally about asking why code _doesn't_ work, for code which does work, but could use improvements, consider codereview.stackexchange.com instead.